# I accidentaly spammed myself - how long do gmail's block SMTP for after such inceidents

Tags: smtp, scripting, google

So, total brainfart! I mis-configured a cron job shortly before I went to bed last night and when I woke up this morning my script, which was supposed to run every 6 hours, had been trying to run every minute of every sixth hour instead - sending two mails via googles SMTP servers per go. Needless to say google nipped this in the bud and started bouncing my mails after the first 80 or so. They also locked me out of the web interface. I have since been able to reset my password and log in and I am able to send mail via the web interface but SMTP access is still being refused.

I'm wondering if anyone knows when I might be able to send again, if ever!? Also is my IP/VPS likely to be blacklisted as a spam box in perpetuity now? Is there anyway to check if your IP is blacklisted and, if it is, would I be better off getting another IP/VPS or following whatever "de-blacklisting" procedure they have? (bearing in mind I'd like a result this century).

I can't find any guidance from google on these matters and, much as I love them, trying to speak to an actual person at Google is like trying to get an audience with the pope. Having tried to wrangle some support out of them on their forums in the past I am loath to go that route (waited 7 months for a response from an employee on their forums once and that was only after bumping and badgering).

Cheers,

Roger - London

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While, I cannot answer you in a straight fashion when you will regain access to it -- as it's largely unknown and not very likely to be anytime soon, my suggestion to it is to simply get another service for your SMTP needs. That includes options like Google Groups for Business and paid Google Apps Mail services.

Comment: Happily it's back on now so the answer would seem to be 12 hours or less. Thanks for your answer though - if it were anything mission critical I would consider using a paid for service.